# Realtek RTL8822CE Bluetooth isn't recognized

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, realtek

Installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS next to Windows 10, but Bluetooth isn't working. In my Laptop there is a Realtek RTL8822CE chip, that works just fine for WiFi but in Bluetooth-Settings it just says "Bluetooth not working. Plug in adapter...". On Windows both WiFi and Bluetooth work just fine. It seems to me that I'm missing some driver or anything but no solution I found online worked for me. Any clues?

Comment: Start by disabling Fast Startup in Windows. Shutdown properly. Boot Ubuntu and test.

Comment: Disabled Fast Startup but no change visible @ChanganAuto

Comment: hmm, perhaps you are missing a dependency or two. Suggest you install a lib. In terminal, enter command:

sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth

[ note: its description states: "This package contains a plugin to make Bluetooth audio devices such as speakers and headsets available to the PipeWire server'. ]

Comment: also, are you certain the RTL8822CE is bluetooth and not wifi ?

Comment: also, the drivers for RTL8822CE are available here... https://github.com/XAIOThaifeng/realtek-linux/blob/master/RTL8822CE/20190709_RTL8822CE_WiFi_linux_v5.7.3_34277_COEX20190531-0e0e_BT_Linux_USB_v3.10_20181220_8822CU_BTCOEX_20190318-0a0a.zip

Comment: also, drivers can be installed by following this page...https://fostips.com/realtek-wifi-drivers-ubuntu-linux-mint/